# Copy a WPF DataGrid into another one without a Colomn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, copy

I need to copy a `DataGrid` removing the last column. I tried with this code and it sets the `ItemSource` correctly, but the columns are empty (in some case I bind object.property):

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

foreach (DataGridColumn dgColumns in source.Columns.Where(i => i.Header != "Sending Result"))
{
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Width = dgColumns.Width,
        Header = dgColumns.Header,
        Binding = new Binding(string.Format("{0}", dgColumns.SortMemberPath)));
    }
}

dg.ItemsSource = source.ItemsSource;
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: do the columns exist (and there is no data), or does the new grid appear to have no columns ?

Comment: it exists, it has 3 rows (correct) but empty

Answer (score 0):

Your problem I think is that you are setting the ItemsSource property property before you are adding your grid into the logical tree.

Try adding the grid to its new parent, and then setting the ItemsSource.

Comment: Sorry i did not get what I have to do. Can you explain me again please?